# How to debug CSS with Firebug for an element that only appears when clicked?

Tags: css, firebug

I want to debug the CSS for a DHTML menu, but the element I want to debug is a submenu, so it only appears when the top element in the menu is clicked.

So I can't use that button on Firebug that shows the CSS for the next element clicked, because when I click on the top menu item it will show the CSS for that element, not its child, and if I expand the menu first and then click on the Firebug button the submenu disappears (it disappears when it loses focus).

Any tips on how to get out of this catch-22?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use firebug console command line to run *click* event. Like `$('#menutab a').click();` If it's needed, you could also set breakpoint to avoid hidding.

Read more in [firebug documentation](http://getfirebug.com/commandline)

Answer (score 1):

Select your element in the HTML tab, directly in the source.

Then, you can hover your page to toggle it.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this I sometimes alter the script slightly in order for the 'hidden' element to stay visible.

In this case, I would perhaps comment out/disable the script code which hides the element on blur. That way you can click the main element, and inspect the now visible item for as long as needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about debuging with all the buttons visible? Or you can still find the elemnt in the HTML tree.

Answer (score 0):

In Opera, you can use Dragonfly (Tools > Advanced > Developer Tools, or Ctrl+Shift+i) to solve this issue.  When the tools are active, clicking on any part of the page will navigate to that section of the HTML side-by-side with its CSS.